# How to retrieve product's data for each product in category view?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

In category view, I want to show an overlay containing product's data, such as brand, manufacturer, tax rate and so on. I can display an overlay (using JavaScript's onmouseover event) and retrieve an id of the product from the URL, but I don't know how to retrieve all data of particular product. What's the simplest way to retrieve all data of particular product based on its id?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get product Information based on Product Id

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id 
echo $_product->getName(); // get Product's name 
echo $_product->getShortDescription(); //get product's short description 
echo $_product->getDescription(); //get Product's Long Description 
echo $_product->getPrice(); //get Product's Regular Price
echo $_product->getSpecialPrice(); //get Product's Special price 
echo $_product->getProductUrl(); //get Product's Url
echo $_product->getImageUrl(); //get Product's image Url
```

If you need attributes like brand and manufacturer for that product you can get in same way.